# MVC Ajax call not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am just learning AJAX and have made a call to my controller but it isn't working.

The problem I am having is that it errors but the alert disappears after a half second and the console error is pretty nonsensical.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My jQuery looks like this:

```
function AjaxVoteClick(itemId) {
    var Url = '@Url.Action("UpVote", "AJAX")' + '?ideaId=' + itemId;

    $.ajax({
        url: Url,
        type: 'POST',
        timeout: 60000,
        dataType: 'json',
        tryCount: 0,
        retryLimit: 3,
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function (httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(httpRequest + "Status = " + textStatus + ", error = " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

When I debug it makes the request ok, and with the correct id but then comes back on error.

The controller is doing what it is supposed to do but I will show it anyway:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public virtual JsonResult UpVote(int ideaId)
    {
        IdeaGenEntities ctx = new IdeaGenEntities();

        var currentIdea = (from m in ctx.Ideas
                          where m.ID == ideaId
                          select m).Single();

        var model = new VoteModel();
        model.Initialize(currentIdea);

        int currentVotes = model.Votes;
        currentVotes += 1;

        currentIdea.Votes = currentVotes;
        ctx.SaveChanges();

        return Json(model);

    }
```

Looking at the Firebug console gives very little. The error goes after half a second unless I have persist on. Then in the header you have this:

> Accept application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
>   Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
>   Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
>   Content-Type    application/json
>   Cookie  __utma=111872281.1986143499.1358265304.1358511066.1358786646.8; __utmz=111872281.1358265304.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); ASP.NET_SessionId=natvmbqvjfnm11deiek1hngi; .ASPXAUTH=4C0D282B36C410B3FA8271342C22B0A4435D35CD8F2BFE5B58E3F2A643993963F56D3F410A4E586FC44DC68B5737F9E7EEC18FB32E629014DECAA43B818DC49358E618CA73815EB1BBF977CE04342146B7F5EA30BB7D0D2328FC3B75F1C4CA65
>   Host    localhos
>   Referer localhost
>   User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0
>   X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest

EDIT: Adding in the Http Fox error.

It says NS_BINDING_ABORTED

and shows this:

> (Request-Line) POST /AJAX/UpVote?ideaId=1 HTTP/1.1
>   Host    localhost
>   User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0
>   Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
>   Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
>   Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
>   X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
>   Referer localhost
>   Cookie  __utma=111872281.1986143499.1358265304.1358511066.1358786646.8; __utmz=111872281.1358265304.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); ASP.NET_SessionId=natvmbqvjfnm11deiek1hngi; .ASPXAUTH=4C0D282B36C410B3FA8271342C22B0A4435D35CD8F2BFE5B58E3F2A643993963F56D3F410A4E586FC44DC68B5737F9E7EEC18FB32E629014DECAA43B818DC49358E618CA73815EB1BBF977CE04342146B7F5EA30BB7D0D2328FC3B75F1C4CA65

And in the Content it says: Error loading content (NS_ERROR_DOCUMENT_NOT_CACHED)

Comment: Sorry, but whats the "nonsensical" error?  Have you tried watching the traffic in Fiddler?

Comment: instead of alerting can you use Console.log so you can give the status and the other variables

Comment: I have included the HttpFox message if that is any help?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         async: false,
         timeout: 60000,
         tryCount: 0,
         retryLimit: 3,
         success: function(data) {
            alert("Success");
         },
         error: function (httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(httpRequest + "Status = " + textStatus + ", error = " + errorThrown);
         }
     });
```

You must specify the content type and if you are working with wcf service your service must be like this

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

public virtual JsonResult UpVote(int ideaId)
{
    IdeaGenEntities ctx = new IdeaGenEntities();

    var currentIdea = (from m in ctx.Ideas
                      where m.ID == ideaId
                      select m).Single();

    var model = new VoteModel();
    model.Initialize(currentIdea);

    int currentVotes = model.Votes;
    currentVotes += 1;

    currentIdea.Votes = currentVotes;
    ctx.SaveChanges();

    return Json(model);

}
```

And if you are using web service your code must contain the following prefix

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public virtual JsonResult UpVote(int ideaId)
    {
        IdeaGenEntities ctx = new IdeaGenEntities();

        var currentIdea = (from m in ctx.Ideas
                          where m.ID == ideaId
                          select m).Single();

        var model = new VoteModel();
        model.Initialize(currentIdea);

        int currentVotes = model.Votes;
        currentVotes += 1;

        currentIdea.Votes = currentVotes;
        ctx.SaveChanges();

        return Json(model);

    }
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. Adding the contentType doesn't help unfortunately. And no Web services.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd try is changing you request from `POST` to `GET` and:

`return Json(model);`

to

`return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately that gave the same error.

Comment: @LexEichner you should now be able to see what is being sent across in the GET Request using Firebug on the network menu. That's what is important here.